# Tkinter-Python- Run a class loop with multiple variables

Tags: class, variables, for-loop, tkinter

I need to re-iterate an algorithm (written as a class) for a certain number of times depending from the input ( a couple of values in this case) which I give him.

For example:

```
class Main:

    def __init__(self, master):

        #here I decide the numbers of iterations (and number of couples values)
        self.n=tk.Entrywidget( master, textvariable=StringVar)
        # now I must create something for the n couple of values,
        # thinking about n couples of entry, don't know how to bind
        # the number of entry widgets to the value of n
        # so I'll create just one
        self.aentry=tk.Entrywidget( master, textvariable= StringVar)
        self.bentry= tk.Entrywidget (master, textvariable= StringVar)
        runbutton= tk.Button( master, command= self.run)

    def run(self):

        self.class1= Class1(self)  

class Class1:  #here I'll write the algoritm

    def __init__(self,master):

        self.a= master.aentry.get()
        self.b= master.bentry.get()
        self.c= self.a +  self.b
```

So I would like to write n couples of values, for example:

n=2 with a1=1, b1=3 and a2=3, b2=5 with 4 and 8 as a result from the Class1 algorithm!
I was thinking about a for cycle but can't do it with multiple variables!

Comment: I do not see an actual question.  If I added the missing import, the code would, I believe run without error.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: This code I wrote is good for 1 couple of variables a and b. What I need to do is to first decide how many couples I need , for example 3 couples (a1,b1) (a2,b2) (a3,b3) then let the code show the number of entry widgets I need ( 6 in this case example) and then run the algorithm 3 times with each couple of values. Don't want to do it for 3 times ( as I can do with the code I wrote here) but only once for every couple of values! Hope I was clear